# Way to automatically name csv file from data frame in python without taking index and header from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, csv

I have a Data Frame with one column consisting of Names
When i access the names from the dataframe as

```
filename = frcl.iloc[[i]]
file = open(''+str(filename)+'.csv', 'w')
```

It creates CSV file with name with index and header in the CSV File Name
Eg; if i have Apple and Bat in Dataframe it creates csv file with 00Apple.csv and 01Bat.csv
how to take dataframe content with out index and header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use panda's method `to_string()` and specify the argument `index=False` to avoid including the row's index.

```py
filename = frcl.iloc[[i]].to_string(index=False)
file = open(''+filename+'.csv', 'w')
```

Comment: `filename = frcl.iloc[[i]].to_string(index=False,header=0)` This worked thank you.